# image box alignment issue is IE

Tags: css, image

enter image description herePlease help me to fix this issue in IE.
It works fine in Chrome, FF

Please check this URL http://scs-qa.com/panamera/trading.html

[image]

Comment: I suggest you also take a screenshot in both IE and FF, and upload it with your question. Click the picture icon when editing a question to upload an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="trading-img-box">
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('trading6').style.display='block';document.getElementById('body-below-otherpage-small-trading').style.display='none'">
<img class="trading-img" src="img/trading6.png">
**<a>**
<h1 class="trading-h1">Marble</h1>
<p class="trading-p">We set ourselves at the..</p>
</div>
```

in this box your not closing your anchor tag.

also add:

```
<p style="height:0; clear:both;"></p>
```

to make sure your background wraps properly, you could add overflow:auto instead. But i've ran into issues in opera with that forcing a scroll sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening due to unclosed anchor `<a>` tag in **trading-img-box `<div>`** having info about `Marble`

```
<div class="trading-img-box">
    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('trading6').style.display='block';document.getElementById('body-  below-otherpage-small-trading').style.display='none'">
        <img class="trading-img" src="img/trading6.png">
    <a> <<<<<< ------ Unclosed Anchor Tag
    <h1 class="trading-h1">Marble</h1>
    <p class="trading-p">We set ourselves at the..</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put overflow:auto on to the element #body-below-otherpage-small-trading